# How to take large number of inputs in microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

I am very new to microcontroller and embedded system. So, this is a very basic question. I need to read 16 bit data from approximately 190 devices. That is to say, ~190 devices will send data at a time and the data need to be read simultaneously or at least under 1 microsecond. Is it possible to do it and how? Any reference or tutorial would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: In light of the comments, the format is 16 bit word from each device. Sorry for saying 1 microsecond, it should be 1 millisecond. My mistake. What I am trying to do is to build an actuator with ~190 poles. Each pole is excited individually based on its state sent from a hall sensor attached to it. The microcontroller have to read the 16 bit words of all poles and activate specific individual poles. I know how to do this next part. I just have know idea how to read the sensor data of so many poles.

Comment: "send data": in what form? Which kind of devices?

Comment: if each of these data streams sends 16 bit, then 190 devices in less than one microsecond implies a data rate of 3 Gb/s. This is unrealistic for a microcontroller to process; nothing in a microcontroller has that bandwidth, not even the connection from the CPU core to its memory controller. Your system design makes no sense – you will need to explain in much more detail what you're trying to do, and why, before we can qualifiedly help you!

Comment: +1 for Marcus, it might be a better option to timestamp the data to know when it was acquired, then transfer it at a more reasonable rate. You'll have to give more details.

Comment: OK, so if you need the information for real time control, then it can't be timestamped. 190 every millisecond is manageable, but I'm sure you would like to avoid a huge mess of wires, so... what protocol(s) do the sensors talk? Is it analog, SPI, I2C, etc? Can you give link to datasheet/documentation for sensors? What is the distance between sensors and main CPU/micro? (for logistics, cabling, what type of protocol to use, etc)

Comment: Also, is it like a linear actuator, where the sensors around the position will see some action, but sensors far away won't do anything, or do you need all the 190 sensors all the time? Basically, do you want to get all the sensors all the time, or to just get the ones you need?

Comment: With that number of sensors, you really need to think about how to interface them. Do they have a digital interface? Or will you need one ADC channel per sensor?

Comment: @bobflux, Sorry, I don't know about the protocols and I am still not at the stage to decide specific sensor. However, the sensor's output will be digital. The distance is approximately 30cm. Ideally, I would like to have all the sensors read at all times.

Comment: OK, SPI will work fine for 30cm and 3 Mbit/s ; you'll probably need a decoder to multiplex chip selects

Comment: If you don’t know what sensor, then you’re starting at the wrong end. Figure at exactly what sensor, how fast you REALLY need to read it then you can work with real numbers. Otherwise you could be bolting a jet engine to a pushbike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPI will work fine for 30cm and 3 Mbit/s, but you will need a decoder to multiplex chip selects and address each sensor when its turn comes.

It's a bit too fast for I2C, unless you use several I2C busses.

However, you're taking this problem from the wrong end. You should select the sensor first, then consider how the whole thing will be constructed, how many boards or modules, and how to fabricate them.

Since large boards tend to be expensive to manufacture, it could be interesting to put a number of sensors on a more "standard" board, and have several of these linked through connectors or cables.

In this case, the protocol that the sensor talks may not be the same as the protocol used to talk to the board.

For example you could have one microcontroller per board, with say 16 analog inputs, and cheap analog sensors. The local micro does the analog to digital conversion, and then outputs the data for all 16 sensors via SPI on a connector. In this case, all the micros on all the boards can acquire in parallel, which makes the ADC throughput in samples per second much less critical.

If I2C sensors happen to be cheaper, then you can use a local I2C bus on each board. It won't be able to manage 190 sensors, but a microcontroller on each board can query the sensors, buffer the data, and sent it over a faster link like SPI to the main controller.